# Can anyone offer information on this WWI[?] shell?

Tags: world-war-one, identification

Can anybody offer any information on this shell. [image: Im] led to believe its WW1.

It is a Brass Centrefire.  The base is marked 47.R. at 12 o'clock.  From 8 o'clock through 3 o'clock it is marked:

- 8 through 5: MA.I.1 6-16.
- 4: Unknown symbol, a makers mark?
- 3: Grenade symbol

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can we get a clearer picture of the symbols on the right, please? Also, is it rimmed or rimmless? And what is the case and rim diameter and case length?

Comment: MAI could be Manufacture d'Armes Issy-les-Moulineaux.

Comment: I have the exact same markings. Was anyone able to identify the shell and it's country of origin?

Comment: @BrettR.Pasquarella If you ask your own question, and fill in the details I asked about, I can give it a go.